# java.io.FileNotFoundException while uploading a file to web server

Tags: java, file-upload, network-programming, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to upload a log file from an applet. The applet uploads a file to a web application (environment Struts 2, Jboss) and receives response (string) from the server

I am using following code to connect, upload a (log) file and receive server response from a application hosted on localhost on Jboss, running at port 8080 :

```
byte[] myData = aData.getBytes();
/* Uploading the data */
URL myURL = new URL(aURL);
URLConnection myConnection = myURL.openConnection();

myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
myConnection.setUseCaches(false);
myConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

OutputStream myOutputStream = myConnection.getOutputStream();
myOutputStream.write(myData);
myOutputStream.flush();
myOutputStream.close();

/* Getting the response */
InputStream myInputStream = myConnection.getInputStream();
byte myBytes[] = new byte[1024];

StringBuffer myStringBuilder = new StringBuffer();
int myReadCount = myInputStream.read(myBytes);

while (myReadCount > 0) {
    myStringBuilder.append(new String(myBytes, 0, myReadCount));
    myReadCount = myInputStream.read(myBytes);
}

return myStringBuilder.toString();
```

On server side, Struts 2 is being used and and action is called to receive this file. The Following code is called at server side :

```
InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

byte[] appletLog = UploadUtil.readFromInputStream(inputStream);

 //appletLog saved in db here;

return UPLOAD_RESPONSE_SUCCESS;
```

Please note that the server side code executes fine, without any exception etc and file is saved in database successfully.

But right after that a  **java.io.FileNotFoundException:** is thrown at line **[EDIT]** `InputStream myInputStream = myConnection.getInputStream();`. I could not find the reason. I would really appreciate if someone can point out mistakes and provide Hints.

Comment: As you said you use Struts2, let me know what does the result UPLOAD_RESPONSE_SUCCESS point to. Is it a page response?

Comment: @JamesJithin: Its a String. Defined as public static final String UPLOAD_RESPONSE_SUCCESS = "0001";

Comment: Is it possible your client-side code is running twice, the first time with the correct data, and the second time with an empty output stream?

Comment: If you are handling the file saving in an action method, it will obviously return the result name. This should be mapped in the struts.xml and then the forward happens as required. Am I right?

Comment: @UmerHayat Did you find any solution? I am also having same problem.